# Android studio inherit class from external module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have an android studio project with several external modules (modules are located on different file paths) and I can`t manage to make the Android Studio see the abstract class from a module.

Some of the modules depends on other modules, eg: ModuleA is a dependency for ModuleB and ModuleB is a dependency to my main app module. The ModuleB can see the abstract class from ModuleA but my main app module cannot see the abstract class from ModuleB.

- I have included on my main app module in the gradle file the module dependency

  `dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

  compile project(':ModuleB')
  }`
- I have only **one** settings.gradle which is located on the root of the main app module. In the settings.gradle I have file paths to the modules I use in this project.

In my main app module I have a class projectHelper that extends abstract class from **ModuleB**. eg:

```
public class projectHelper extends Helper {

}
```

And whatever I tried I cannot make the main module app to see the abstract Helper class from ModuleB module.

Gradle sync passes ok but the Studio reports that the Helper class cannot be resolved.

I have tried to include the package from the ModuleB, even extend the class something like "extends com.android.ModuleB.Helper" but the class nor the package cannot be resolved.

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and Android NDK with com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0 plugin.

I have done this in Eclipse and it works without a problem.

It also offers me to move the class from ModuleB to my main App module (but I cannot do that), see image: (I had to obscure the package names).
[image: module]

Comment: I have established that if I extend a class from a module that does NOT contain NDK code, it works fine. I can extend an abstract class in my main module app, but only when I try to extend the module that contains c++ and Java code it does not. The module builds ok, but it doesn`t work as a dependency. Pure Java module works with pure Java main module app, only if it contains NDK code it cannot be extended. Maybe this is an experimental plugin error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, this can`t be done with experimental NDK plugin.

I have solved this with android.productFlavors. The point is to make the code beside your main dir in separate dir, like flavour1, give it java->packageName>someClass.java. It must have the same package name as the main app, but ignore that because you can change it in gradle at that specific build flavour

```
create("googleFree") {
        applicationId = "com.example.mySpecialPackage"
    }
```

and that package name will be replaced in the manifest when the APK is built.

I have learned this from this link http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/